# Unable to connect to Node JS localhost API from android app in emulator

Tags: android, node.js, android-emulator, localhost

I run Node JS on localhost. Trying to call one of the Node API http://10.0.2.2:8000/api_users from android app running in the emulator. FileNotFound exception or FailedToConnect exception is what I end up with.

Am I doing anything wrong? Is there another way to connect to the NodeJS API running locally?

Kindly help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Right now, your API isn’t working, because Android EMULATES a phone, having their own local, on the phone, but not linked at all from your phone to your computer, that’s why there is no access to your API via localhost. Right now, the emulator tries to access the localhost from the phone. You can solve that by using a local IP Adress

Comment: yes, I tried with my local IP address which is something like http://192.168.0.5:8000/api_users . From the Android Emulator browser, I can access the API. Issue with the same API when I access it from app running in Emulator.

Comment: When accessing API url, FileNotFound Exception is what I get.
Also, I tried with 10.0.2.2 address and that says FailedToConnect.